# Toggle wordpress content

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, toggle

I am trying to intergrate [this](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/easy-toggle-jquery-tutorial/) into wordpress. Is there a way to get custom divs for certain post I basicly just want to make a page like [this](http://s72956.gridserver.com/dev/toggle/toggle.html) updatible in wordpress. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to make a Wordpress page, you could use custom page templates, so that the specific page looked different than the rest of the site.

To do that, you would need to make a copy of single.php, change the HTML that you wanted to, and add this (below) to the top of the file. Then place it into your theme directory, and choose it as a page template on the page editor.

```
/*
Page Template: Template Name
*/
```

Reference [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages) for more info.